# Given the result of a dot product and one of the vectors, is it possible to find the other vector?

Tags: vectors

When processing geometry the dot product or $n\cdot L$ (where $n$ is the normal, $L$ is the light direction) is baked into the $w$ of a vertex, but since the $L$ is constant I wanted to know if there is any way to get $n$ without changing the backend processing?

Comment: No.  $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not even in the two dimensional case. In the 2-D case, however, you can narrow it down to one of two directions which are obtained from a quadratic equation:

$$
\vec{n}\cdot \vec{L} = n_x L_x + n_yL_y = k \implies n_y = \frac{k-n_xL_x}{L_y}
\\n_x^2 + n_y^2 = 1\implies n_x^2 + \left( \frac{k-n_xL_x}{L_y} \right)^2 = 1
$$
which is a quadratic equation giving two possible solutions of $n_x$.

In the 3-D case a whole circle of answers is possible.

Comment: A whole plane of answers, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Given a vector $\vec v$ and scalar $a$, there is no unique solution to the equation
$$\vec v\cdot\vec w=a.$$

Consider the case $\vec v=\vec k$, and $a=0$.  Then any vector of the form
$x\vec i+y\vec j$ is a solution to 
$$\vec v\cdot \vec w=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

You can't recover **n** from **n.L** and **L**:

Suppose **v** is any vector perpendicular to **L**, so that **v.L** $=0$. Then **(n+v).L = n.L + v.L = n.L**. So any such **n+v** also satisfies your condition on **n**.

Comment: Why the bold symbols instead of formatted math?

Comment: @TMM: What a strange question! Many people use bold text to indicate a vector.

Comment: Even so, why not bold formatted math then? Please give me an example of a respected m.SE member (or any serious paper in mathematics literature) who does not use formatted math for formulas/symbols.

Comment: (Using `mathbf`: $\mathbf{(n+v).L = n.L + v.L = n.L}$ instead of **(n+v).L = n.L + v.L = n.L**)

Comment: @TMM: Edit it if it makes you feel better.

Comment: I am just suggesting that most people would agree that formulas look nicer when formatted with TeX, and even boldface math can easily be achieved this way. If you choose to interpret this is a personal attack on "your style", then forget it.